# Selenium - driver.find_element_by_css_selector can't find the element (c#)

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to get selenium to click on a selection in a tree however I'm not getting anywhere.

Could anyone help:

[image]

The code i'm using is as follows:

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.DoubleClick(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#reportsTree_tv_active > div.k-bot > span.k-in > div.menu-security-item > div.menu-security-label"))).Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Dom snippet missing the previous line. Can you add it

Comment: Could you please also add the versions of your Selenium package and the driver you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your selector is correct. You can simplify it to

```
"li#reportsTree_tv_active div.menu-security-label"
```

I think you get the correct element. Maybe the double click doesn't do what you need.
If element couldn't be located, you would get `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException`.
Try getting an element like this:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li#reportsTree_tv_active div.menu-security-label");
```

And then check if its `Text` is `"Worksheets"`

Comment: I get the no such element: Unable to locate Element: ("method":"css selector","selector":"li#reportsTree_tv_active div.menu-security-label")

Comment: also tried a regular click:             Actions act = new Actions(driver);
            var element = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("li#reportsTree_tv_active div.menu-security-label");
            element.Click();
            act.DoubleClick(element).Build().Perform();

Comment: Maybe you should wait for it to appear. Do you have Implicit wait set up?

Comment: I do, i can try to put in an explicit wait, but there isn't much of a lag or anything between the actions.

Comment: Maybe you can give a link or copy of an html to try. Because the CssSelector is correct for sure.

Comment: The odd thing is when i use //*[@id='reportsTree']/ul/li[3] and I check the console it can get it, but it just can't click it